# How do you access the menus given a QMenuBar?

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt how do you recover the menus given a populated `QMenuBar`?

They do not seem to be the menu bar's children. For example, after the following (where the menu creation functions succeed and do what you expect)

```
menuBar()->addMenu(create_file_menu(this));
menuBar()->addMenu(create_view_menu(this));
auto children = menuBar()->children();
auto first_child = children[0];
```

`children` ends up with a size of 1 and that one child, `first_child`, is some object of type `QMenuBarExtension`. I was expecting to get two children with the first being the file menu.

I'm using Qt6 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A QMenu is added to a QMenuBar internaly via `QWidget::addAction(menu->menuAction())` (see <QtInstallPath/src\widgets\widgets\qmenubar.cpp>.
From QWidget you can retrieve the added QActions via `QWidget::actions()` - method which returns a list of associated QActions. In your specific example `menuBar()->actions()` should retrieve at least two actions for your menus.

However, there seems to be no way to get from a `QMenu::menuAction()` - created QAction back to the associated menu. Therefore you may need to store a pointer to your created QMenu - objects on your own.

Comment: ah, yeah, i didnt realize toplevel menus have actions associated with them. Don't really need the QMenu since I can enable/disable the action.